# R: Plot fixed axis range for each plot in a loop

Tags: r, loops, plot

I have a sample data set for which I plot several png files divided by groups (in this case by ID) in a loop. 
A question that concerns the x axis: How could I introduce a fixed range (lets say from 1940 to 2014 in every graph) into the for loop, so that the x-axis always corresponds to this range (case1) but if values in `YEAR` before 1940 are included, do the plot scenario with the whole group which is plotting the axis ranges automatically like in the for-loop introduced in the code above (case 2)?
Case 1 with the sample data would be for the group with `ID 259 (NAME2)` and case 2 would be for the group with `ID 47 (NAME1)`

Here is my code:

```
xy <- data.frame(NAME=c("NAME1", "NAME1","NAME1","NAME1","NAME2","NAME2","NAME2"),ID=c(47,47,47,47,259,259,259),YEAR=c(1932,1942,1965,1989,2007,2008,2014),VALUE=c(0,NA,-6,-16,0,-9,-28))

ind <- split(x = xy,f = xy[,'ID'])

### PLOT
for(i in 1:length(ind)){
  png(names(ind[i]), width=3358, height=2329, res=300)
  par(mar=c(6,8,6,5))
  plot(ind[[i]][,c('YEAR','VALUE')],
       type='n',
       main=ind[[i]][1,'NAME'],
       xlab="Time [Years]", 
       ylab="Length change [m]")  
  # plot axis
  axis(1, at = seq(1000,2030,10), cex.axis=1, labels=FALSE, tcl=-0.3) 
  # plot points and lines
  points(ind[[i]][,c('YEAR','VALUE')], type="l", lwd=2)
  points(ind[[i]][,c('YEAR','VALUE')], type="p", lwd=1, cex=1,   pch=21, bg='white')  
  # plot vertical line through 0
  abline(h=0)

  dev.off() 
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you mean to use `abline(h=0)` since the vertical line at 0 would be thousands of units to the left, probably a couple of blocks away.

Comment: my bad. you are absolutely right @BondedDust! I will edit the OP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it! Starting with a blank plot and then adding points/lines is perfect. Change your initial `plot` call to include the ranges you want, and you're good to go:

```
x.range <- c(1940, 2014)
if (min(ind[[i]][, 'YEAR'], na.rm = T) < 1940) {
    x.range <- range(ind[[i]][, 'YEAR'], finite = T)
} 
plot(x = x.range,
     y = range(ind[[i]][,'VALUE'], finite = T),
     type='n',
     main=ind[[i]][1,'NAME'],
     xlab="Time [Years]", 
     ylab="Length change [m]")
```

Note that these plots will still have different `y` axes.

Comment: thanks! the problem is that I have gaps in my plots that are defined by NA values and in this case this method doesn't work (error in plot.window(...): need finite ylim values'. I changed the sample data in order to make it clearer.

Comment: That's not really a problem. Just put `finite = T` inside `range` (see `?range`). See updates also for the case where date is pre-1940.

Comment: thanks. just using my sample data above I get an error: in ind[[ind]] subscript out of bounds. What could I do about it?

Comment: @redshoe Just using your sample data I get two plots and no errors. Make sure you start from a clean R session, and make sure you completely replace your `plot()` call with my code.